# Change the "SuperFlat" world generator in minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I started minecraft modding with mcp.

Now i want to make some changes in the superflat world generator. The one that generates just one level bedrock and three levels of dirt. I want to use this generator as a basis for awesome things like giant houses.

But i cant find the right class. Which class is responsible for the "superflat" generator?

///////////////////////
Edit:

Found it!

It's called `ChunkProviderFlat.java`

Comment: you should provide an answer for your question instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: i have to wait 8 hours util i can answer my own question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

It's called ChunkProviderFlat.java